# webgl canvas doesn't respect style dimensions

Tags: html5-canvas, mobile-safari

I'm trying to change the size of a canvas while keeping the size it's displayed constant. This work well in desktop safari and not in mobile safari...

```
var screenWidth = window.innerWidth,
  screenHeight = window.innerHeight,
  extraRatio = 0.4;

var devicePixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1,
 backingStoreRatio = gl.webkitBackingStorePixelRatio || 1,
 ratio = devicePixelRatio / backingStoreRatio * extraRatio;

gl.canvas.width = screenWidth * ratio;
gl.canvas.height = screenHeight * ratio;
gl.canvas.style.width = screenWidth + 'px';
gl.canvas.style.height = screenHeight + 'px';
```

I'm using the `extraRatio` to control how much computation goes into rendering the canvas (I'm rendering 360 video that can get pretty intense) So I want the canvas to always be full screen, and control the pixelation with `extraRatio`

This works perfectly on desktop Safari, but not in mobile. In desktop, no matter what is `extraRatio`, the canvas going to be full screen. In mobile, the canvas is drawing from the top left corner and filling `2*extraRatio` of the screen (if `extraRatio > 0.5`, it goes off screen, else the rest of the screen is black)

In desktop, `devicePixelRatio = backingStoreRatio = 1` and in mobile `devicePixelRatio = backingStoreRatio = 2`, not sure how this comes into play but there seems to be a 2 somewhere.